# Issue with mixed reality system check- loading indefinitely

Tags: virtual-reality, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to use HP Reverb G2 with my computer (Windows 10, intel i7, 32 Ram, Quatro T2000 and Intel UHD Graphics). One of the first steps is to open the mixed reality portal and check the system requirements. What should only take a few seconds, is loading forever.

I already looked everyone and couldn't find any solution for the problem. Have anyone some idea what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem.

1. Open regedit (windows + R, write regedit).
2. Goes to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic
3. Change the value of “FirstRunSucceeded” to 1.

Now it skips the system check and open directly the Widwons Mixed Reality Portal.